# CSS Sublinks not right

Tags: html, css

Does NOT work in IE7:

My CSS:

```
#main_navi  li{
  vertical-align:middle;
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
    display:inline;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline; /*IE7*/
    *zoom:1; /*IE7*/

}
#nav ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;
}  

#nav ul li ul {
  position:absolute;
  top:104px;
  width:1059px;
  padding:0;
  margin:0 0 0 -40px;
  background:#e9e9e9;
  /*
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  */
  /*
  border-radius: 5px; 
  */
  border:1px solid #dedad6;
}  

.ds ul {
  display:block; 
}


.dsn ul {
  display:none; 
}

a.main_navi_0:link, a.main_navi_0:visited {
  color:#696969;
  font-size:16px;
  font-weight:200;
  font-family: 'Allerta', sans-serif;
  height:65px;
  padding:40px 10px 0 20px;
  display:inline;
  float:left;
  /*
  text-align:center;   
  */
}


a.main_navi_1:link, a.main_navi_1:visited {
  font-size:16px;
  font-weight:200;
  font-family: 'Allerta', sans-serif;
  height:65px;
  padding:40px 10px 0 20px;
  display:inline;
  float:left;
  text-align:center;  
  color: #3c94e2;
}

a.main_navi_0:hover, a.main_navi_1:hover {
  color:#000;
  border-bottom:5px solid #3c94e2;
}

a.sub_navi_0:link, a.sub_navi_0:visited {
color:#696969;
font-size:13px;
font-weight:200;
font-family: 'Allerta', sans-serif;
height:25px;
padding:5px 10px 0 10px;
display:inline;
float:left;
text-align:center;
/*
z-index:999;
*/
position:relative;
border-bottom:2px solid #dedad6;    
}

a.sub_navi_1:link, a.sub_navi_1:visited {
color:#696969;
font-size:13px;
font-weight:200;
font-family: 'Allerta', sans-serif;
height:25px;
padding: 5px 10px 0 10px;
/*
display: inline;
float: left;
*/
text-align: center;
/*
z-index:999;
*/
position: relative;
border-bottom: 2px solid #3c94e2; 
}

a.sub_navi_0:hover,  a.sub_navi_1:hover {
color:#000;
border-bottom:2px solid #3c94e2;
}
```

My html-file:

```
<div id="nav">
    <div id="logo">
        <div id="main_navi">
            <ul>
                <li class="dsn">
                <a class="main_navi_0" href="ueber-uns.html">Über uns</a>
                <ul>
                </li>
                                    </ul>
                 <li class="dsn">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My output in IE7

```
Link1 Link2 Link3
  SL11 SL11        //SL11 = SubLink 11 SL12 = Sublink 12 Matrix
        SL21 SL22
```

I want it that way:

```
Link1 Link2 Link3
SL11  SL12
//or
SL21  SL22
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Is it me or does the code given not reflect what they are talking about... Also you didn't even put the `CSS`...

Comment: post your complete code.

Comment: i have updated my answer, check it out and let me know if you have any doubts and mark it as answer if you found my answer helpful, thanks..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div id="nav">
            <div id="logo">
                <div id="main_navi">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Link1 
                            <ul>
                                <li>Link 11</li>
                                <li>Link 21</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>Link3 
                            <ul>
                                <li>Link 12</li>
                                <li>Link 22</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul{
    list-style-type:none;
}
#nav ul li
{
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
     padding:10px;
}
#nav ul li ul li
{
    clear:left;
    margin-left:-50px;
    padding:10px;
}
```

## [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BvJv2/)

**Output:**

[image]

You can also check this fiddle for Pure CSS Sub - Sub Menu..!!

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a4vD3/19/)

Answer (score 0):

Your tags format is wrong, you should have something like

```
    <div id="horizontalmenu">
    <div id="logo">
        <div id="main_navi">
            <ul>
                <li>Link1
                    <ul>
                        <li>Link 11</li>
                        <li>Link 21</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Link2
                    <ul>
                        <li>Link 12</li>
                        <li>Link 22</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Link3</li>
                <li>Link4</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

anyway, I prepared full example of horiznal menu, [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/adelassi/9rhbL/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Your markup is invalid (you open 2 ul elements, but close one). My guess is that that is your problem.